# malformed pdf document asks to save changes

Tags: pdf, save, eof, dompdf, malformed

We have this big web project where the user can print the html to pdf. We are using dompdf, and have somewhat fixed the long cell issues that cause the pdf to have several blank pages. Now the issue is that the saved pdf, when closing, always asks if the user wants to save changes. I have verified that the pdf has the proper %%EOF, and have checked for object consistency. What else could be causing this problem?

Comment: If you supplied a sample PDF, we could inspect and analyze it.

Comment: just solved it, forgot to add pdf, ty anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [introduction to pdf](http://www.gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF) I realized that if the pdf was modified, I had to accomodate all the object offsets so that they would point to the object start location.